# .NET application hangs and I can't debug it

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on a multithreaded C# server for Syslog. I'm trying to perform a long-running experiment, but I found that after one hour the server hangs (after a certain time, logging stops).

I tried then to run it in `Debug` mode in Visual Studio and when I found it hanging and tried to press Pause in order to get useful information on where the threads were, Visual Studio said that Remote Debugging Monitor crashed. It's a local application.

What can I do to pause the process and get useful information about thread status?

Comment: Force the Platform target to x86 so you don't have to deal with the remote debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately, no result. I'm running Windows 7 x64. Should I force x64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WinDBG** is a good alternative for low level issues that VS cannot trap. You can find more information here: [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Managed stack explorer](http://mse.codeplex.com/) will poll a managed application and log what is currently happening.

[This article](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/07/sos-from-your-production-environment/) may also be useful (section about hang mode dump), but will require debugging a crash dump file (WinDbg is not as easy to absorb as Visual Studio and will take some time to learn).

Comment: Hmm... I tried it but it only shows devenv.exe and dexplore.exe (I have 3 instances of VS2008 running, 1 for server debug, 1 for client debug and another idle)...

Comment: Just attach MSE to the current running process, no debugger needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would try StingyJack's recommendation but I believe there is no replacement for lightweight tracing using Debug.WriteLine() and using Sysinternal's DebugView to see what is happening.

This would be where *I* would start. **VS is not powerful enough to help you debug a multi-threaded service.** It can sometimes even lie on the state of objects and bear in mind, when you are *debugging*, you *disrupt the normal flow of events*.

Comment: Though I love the ease of debugging in VS, @Aliostad is right - even in the best-case scenario, the order of events when you have the debugger attached may not mirror the order of events when it's not, so race conditions and other bugs you have in production may disappear when attempting to trap them in a debugger. Debug.WriteLine is failsafe and (though painful) the only totally trustworthy way to debug multi-threaded apps.

Comment: Debugging random deadlock with tracing is very tricky, the altered timing may solve the deadlock condition.  Or trigger it immediately instead of having to wait for an hour.  But of course that only happens when the Moon is in Aquarius.

Comment: I'm sure that if it was a managed deadlock, I would have been able to detect it. In the past, I always succeeded in detecting them. Fortunately, I might have isolated a component that is a potential source of trouble